# can we clear errono after function call

Tags: c++, posix, errno

I have some function call like below, and want to print success after success call, but got failure, even the function actually behave correctly.

```
int myfunction() {
    // does some linux sys call for example
    int error = run_cmd ("ifconfig usb10 up");
    int syserrorno = errno; 
    strerror(syserrorno);
    return error;
}

int main(){
int error =1;
int retry = 0;
do {
    error = myfunction();
    retry++;
}
while ( error !=-1 && retry <3);
return 0;
}
```

Basically I tried to:

1. Run a syscal via myFunction, return error = 1 if fail or 0 if success.
2. The return error in myFunction is the same as in syscal.
3. The syscal is a posix spawn command that I reuse from library.
4. If there is error, print error, redo 3 times.

So I have 1st run of syscall unsuccessfully; it returns error and print out "unavailabe resources". It is expected.

The second time is successful as I check the usb10 and it is up. But it still prints out the same error instead of success.

Is there a way to print it correctly ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When using `errno`, always set `errno=0;` before calling the function(s) whose status you want to check. C library and POSIX functions will set `errno` to a non-zero value if they encounter an error, but they do *not* reset it to zero if they succeed.

(The reason they work this way: When a function reporting via `errno` is actually implemented in terms of other functions, you don't want a later success to make `errno` forget about an earlier failure. This also makes it possible for user code to set `errno=0;`, call a number of closely-related library functions, and just check for overall success or failure after all of those calls.)

Comment: If we have concurrent running system, if I set errno=0, while another threads may have error, would it mess up their error report ? 

how do we know which errono reporting is for which process, which function call ?

Comment: @MinhPham Each thread has its own `errno` variable.